# SVN Rename directory, maintain file history

Tags: svn, history, rename

I originally created my svn repository without the suggested trunk, branches, tags structure.

It looks something like this.

```
/src
/src/file.txt
/src/file2.txt
```

I used TortoiseSVN to rename the /src directory to /projectName/trunk/src; however, now I can't easily view the history of a file within the directory structure using Show Log.  Is there a better way to do this to maintain a continuous history of all the files?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tortoise defaults to `Stop on copy` when viewing logs, if I remember right.  If you uncheck that box on the log viewer, then you'll be able to see the entire history of the files/directories.

Comment: Thanks.  That's all it took.  Happy to know I didn't wipe my history out! :)

Comment: Thanks Jamessan , I have browsed hundred of links and finally found the answer here.

Comment: ommmgggggggg bless your soul