# TortoiseSVN: Move file does not preserve history

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am attempting to move a file to another folder inside a TortoiseSVN repository, and the revision history is not being preserved.  I have tried moving the files using the Repo-browser (right-click drag the files and select "Move items to here") as well in the working folder (right-click drag, select "SVN Move versioned files here," and commit the parent folder).  In both cases the history is not preserved.  I have read the TortoiseSVN manual as well as some other posts from people and am postitive those are the ways to do it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104289/svn-rename-directory-maintain-file-history/

Comment: If I remember correctly (can't look it up right now), the history viewer of TortoiseSVN only shows the history up to a move or copy, and there is a check box to make it dig deeper.

Comment: Did you unmark "Stop on Copy/Rename" in your History-browser?

Comment: Yes, and I still can't see the history.

Comment: One thing that is different about my repository is that is was created from a backup.  Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Another bizzare thing: when I create a new folder in the repo browser, that action does not show up in the log.  Could my repository be corrupted?

Comment: Well, if creating a folder remotely does not create a folder, without producing an error message, then there's definitely something wrong with your setup.  But to resolve this, you'd better start your question with a different angle.  Kind of setup (svn/http), permissions, check for IP config, etc. etc.

Comment: I'm not using TortoiseSVN remotely, it's all on my C drive.  Every once in a while I copy the repository to a back-up folder.  My current respository is from one of those backups.

Comment: Are you actually committing your changes? Logs aren't generated until you commit your changes to the remote repository.

Comment: Again, I'm not using it remotely, both the repository and the working folder are on my C drive.  And I don't think you need to commit when doing things in the repo browser, correct?

Comment: Any changes need to be committed for them to create a new log entry.  It doesn't matter whether the central repository is on some remote computer or on your current computer.  No changes in your working directory are made permanent until you commit them.

Comment: But you don't need to commit when doing things in the repo browser, correct?

Answer (score 16):

Subversion and TortoiseSVN absolutely do preserve the file history.  (It is one of the fundamental aspects of SVN.)

Two key points (which you already seem to be aware of):

- You have to use the SVN move/copy/rename commands.  Otherwise, SVN won't be able to know they are the same file.
- When looking at the log for moved/copied/renamed, you have to make sure the "Stop on copy/rename" option is unchecked.  Otherwise, the log will only go back so far.

Now, keep in mind that you need to be looking at the log for something that actually was moved/copied.  Look at the log of the file that was copied.  Don't look at the log of the directory you copied it from, or the directory you copied it to.

Comment: Thanks!  I've got both points covered, but still no history.  And Subversion uses a global revision number, so if I do a "Show log" on the root in the repo browser, I should see the move operation.  For some reason this is not showing up.

Comment: If you show the log at the root of the repo, you should see every change.  What does it show for the revision where you did the move operation?

Comment: Looking at the log window for a folder after a file was renamed:  You should see the file "removed" from the old location and "added" to the new location.  You'll see the "copy from path" and "revision" columns are populated, which shows the file's ancestry.  If you do a show log on the individual file, it will show the history of the file going all the way back (as long as "stop on copy/rename" is unchecked).

Answer (score 10):

The page with the answer has been removed from TortoiseSVN help docs: 
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html>

But still exists in Google cache:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:x7UeADC8BpwJ:tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

> If you want to move files around inside your working copy, perhaps to a different sub-folder, use the right mouse drag-and-drop handler:
>
> select the files or directories you want to move
>
> right drag them to the new location inside the working copy
>
> release the right mouse button
>
> in the popup menu select Context Menu → SVN Move versioned files here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out that after you do the SVN Move versioned files here you can get to the history as long as you select each file. If you try to view the log of the folder it will only show you the copy.