# Move svn folder while keeping history of files

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I am trying to move a svn folder one level up (similar question than [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679318/how-to-move-svn-folder-one-level-up))

The actual structure of my project is `myproject/trunk/trunk` (it seems that I made a mistake when I created the original repository). 
I would like to have `myproject/trunk`.

Using TortoiseSVN, I can right-drag my files one level up, this will keep the history of the whole folder. The point is that, I lost the history of each individual file. Is there a mean to keep both history of the folder and files?

**EDIT**
to sum up:
(1) when my project looks like `myproject/trunk/myfiles` (which I don't want because it duplicates trunk): I can see the complete history from either the folder 'myproject' or any of 'myfiles'
(2) after I right drag 'myfiles' into myproject: the complete history is still available from the folder 'myproject' nut not any more from any of 'myfiles'.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108567/moving-directories-with-history

Comment: Ty @DouglasStead. The answer given in the link you provided is also about the history of the whole folder. But a contributor to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782862/3894837) highlighted the same issue as me

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/108576/3894837), svn does not allow to keep history on directories. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141417/tortoisesvn-move-file-does-not-preserve-history?rq=1)  the history for the files themselves is preserved during a move/copy, but as you say, it looks like the folder history will only show the copy

Comment: In my case, after moving files I am able to see the complete history from the parent folder but the history of a particular file only shows the last commit log (even with "Stop on Copy/Rename" unmarked). So it seems to be the opposite situation of the threads we have found...I am a bit confusing